# Xampp Apache Service Not Starting

Tags: apache, xampp

I have installed xampp 3.2.1 in my virtual machine windows xp.i need mysql and apache services for my project mysql service starts easily but apache service is not staring even if it starts for few seconds it shut downs immediately.

[image: apache error]

1. checked that no other service or application like skype or any other is running on port 80 using xampp control panel Netstat

[image]

2. change the configurations of ports in httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf tried different ports like 1337 and 7331 , 3333 and 4444 , 81 and 444 and many others but no luck.
3. Tried disabling IIS as recommended in forums but again no luck.
4. Stopped Web Client in Services but no solution also recommended to check the path of mysql and apache services in services tab but there is no mysql and apache services in services tab.

Am I missing any configuration or is it virtual machine problem.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: hey guys...is there no one with similar problem or relevant solution....

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, skype application running on your pc is a factor that might disabled the xampp from working.. So ensure you signed out from the skype and start the xampp / wamp again.

Yes, it works after running.

Answer (score 1):

you must change **Port 443** to some other available port number in httpd-ssl.conf  file

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved the same problem. In my event it was about virtual hosts configuration (httpd-vhosts.conf). Probably there was a kind of typo or a wrong command. I deleted all my added virtual hosts, restarted apache in xampp (to see that it is starts running), then added the virtual hosts anew, and one more time restarted xampp.
Best,
Eugene

PS. Make a copy of the file httpd-vhosts.conf for recovery.